# Crashlytics - Unable to get crash reports when the app crashes while not connected to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm using crashytics from Fabric.io in my app.

Here's how I have initialised it in my `MainActivity.java` at the very last of `onCreate()` method:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Here's `build.gradle (Project: abc)` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's `build.gradle (Module: app)` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.abc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

`<meta-data
   android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
   android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 />` is defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` between `<application>` tags.

**The problem is** that I'm unable to get the crash reports whenever the app crashes while not connected to Android Studio though I get the reports when the app crashes while connected to it.

Why is this happening and **how can I** get the crash reports each and every time the app crashes whether connected to Android Studio or not?

Comment: Did you restart the application after the application crashes in any case, secondly is instant run enabled or not. If yes try uninstalling and installing again with instant run feature of.

Comment: @AnuragSingh how instant run feature can affect?

Comment: It may be possible that since you build the first time with fabric you were connected to android studio. But as you disconnect from it your build may not have the latest changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove from `Activity` and put inside **Application** class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

}
```

Don't forget to add name in **Application** tag of `manifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: where is this application class?

Comment: you have to create like how you created activity!

Comment: should I then remove it from MainActivity?

Comment: For testing: you can set `null` to any object which are accessing. it will be crashed with `NPE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136373/discussion-between-kishore-jethava-and-hammad-nasir).